# Can layers from Spatialite db be used as input for a Sextante model?

Tags: qgis, spatialite, sextante, model

I'm trying to build my first models in SEXTANTE and already fail at the start. It seems not to be possible to add a vector layer which derives from a database. Orginally, the layers are from a .mdb. I also imported the layers into a spatialite database.

When running the model with those layers as input, the excutions breaks with an error:

```
Error executing algorithm 0
Wrong value: dbname='P:/pathtodb/Grunddaten.sqlite' key='PKUID' table="monitoring_area" (Geometry) sql=
```

When saving the layers as shape files first and adding to the project, the model runs without a problem.

Is it in general not possible to use layers from db's or do i have to do some special stuff to get the model running?